# How to merge not all summaries in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, summary

I have big graph with two parts, I run in turn. Both has summaries.

I was calling summaries with node

```
merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

but noticed, that it causes tensors in second half of graph evalueted before it has sense.

So, how to merge only summaries of one half of my graph?

Comment: If either of the answers helped you, please mark it a correct so that people know what worked when they come across your question in the future.

Comment: Just a bump again to remind you to accept whichever answer seems best to you so that others know what worked when they come across your question...

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`tf.summary.merge`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/merge), passing a list of the summaries that you want to merge. For example, if you have the summaries:

```
cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar('cost_sum', cost)  # for some 'cost' tensor
grad_summary = tf.summary.scalar('grad_sum', grad)  # for some 'grad' tensor
```

you can merge them by name with:

```
merged = tf.summary.merge([cost_summary, grad_summary])
```

So just make merged summary operators for each part of your graph and call them when it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 9):

assuming you have two lists of summaries of the first and the second graphs, i.e:

```
summaries_first = [tf.summary.image("my_first_graph_input", image), ...]
summary_second = [tf.summary.scalar("my_second_graph_loss"), ..]
```

merge each list into a single summary op:

```
first_graph_summary_op = tf.summary.merge(summaries_first)
second_graph_summary_op = tf.summary.merge(summary_second)
```

now, whenever you execute a `sess.run()` on each graph, evaluate it's corresponding summary op and write it.